# How do I convert enzyme (shallow) to react testing library?

Tags: unit-testing, enzyme, react-testing-library

How can I convert this part of my test to React Testing Library so that I'm not using shallow anymore?

```
const renderComponent = (jsx) => {
  const component = shallow(jsx);
  const title = component.find('.tile-bottom__title');
  const content = component.find('.tile-bottom__text');
  return {
    component,
    title,
    content,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for react-testing-library, you can read the DOM nodes from screen, you can update the function to

```js
const renderComponent = (jsx) => {
  const { container, getByTestId }  = render(jsx);
  const title = getByTestId('tile-bottom__title'); // not class but testId
  const content = getByTestId('tile-bottom__text'); // // not class but testId
  return {
    // component, // not needed to return component as you can use `screen` for further assertions
    title,
    content,
  };
};
```

Comment: and what is the container for?

Comment: It's used as a reference to see where the component is rendered.